# Should I change the CSS stylesheet from JSP or from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

What would be the best way to change the CSS stylesheet?

Example: add a CSS class if the value of an input field is positive and another CSS class if the value is negative

It can be done from JSP and JavaScript also. Supposing the application includes both JSP and JavaScript, which code goes in JSP and which one goes to JavaScript?

Btw, the application does not support JavaScript OFF.

Comment: If you are using jQuery in your application then it's so easy to do this

Comment: It depends on if you want the class to change over a postback, or immediately on the client. I'd go with client side unless there is some processing required on the server.

Comment: Rohit, thanks for the answer. However, I wasn't asking how to do this but what would be the best approach to do it, from jsp or from js. Rory, in my case a server request is done and as a response I retrieve a positive or a negative value and I should change the class based on this. So for this case you would go with JSP?